# GAS Scan all spreadsheets in folder and change a specific cell value and sheet name?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```js
function getAllSheetsInFolder () {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  Logger.log("file length: " + contents.length);

  var file;
  var data;
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Class Data")
  sheet.clearContents();

  var numOfFiles = contents.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < numOfFiles; i++) {
    file = contents[i];
    Logger.log("count: "  + i);

    //Reset to null on every iteration 
    var onecell = null;
    var theRange = null;

    var theFileType = file.getFileType();
    Logger.log("theFileType: " + theFileType);

if (theFileType==DocsList.FileType.SPREADSHEET) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getRange(2,7);
  cell.setValue('RTI')


    };
  }
}
}
```

I am looking to write a GAS that scans all of the spreadsheets in a folder and changes the value of cell  (G2) in every spreadsheet.  Can it be set up to scan all spreadsheets in the folders and subfolders?  Or just each spreadsheet in a specific folder.

I am also looking to change the name of of the 4th sheet in each of the spreadsheets as well.   I just wanted to see if you guys thought this was a possibility before I start messing with some code.

Comment: Yes, every one of your ideas is possible, I can only think of a recursive function tomgo trough all folders, all the other ideas are pretty simple.

Comment: Is your code bound to a spreadsheet, or run as a Stand Alone App?  And how do you ultimately want to trigger the code to run?

Comment: Thanks for replying to me.  I was going to run it stand alone.  I basically have a big number of sub folders in a root folder with identical spreadsheets, and I want to change cell (2,7) G3 to RTI in each as well as change the name of sheet 4 to RTI data, without having to open them all and change them one by one.  Thanks again

Comment: I am messing with the code you provided, I edited the code above with my last test.  Not working yet.  The code at the end works if I run it from SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); from within the spreadsheet, but I cant get it to run stand alone by getFolderById("ID"); etc.

Comment: @SandyGood The code provided above doesn't error out but it doesn't seem to change anything in the spreadsheets in the given folder.  I have figured out how to get the code to do exactly what I want, I just can't get it to iterate through the folder.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the code.  I substituted `DriveApp` for `DocsList`, but they behave very differently.  `DocsList` is deprecated, and even though it still works, you should change to `DriveApp`.  I totally re-wrote the code, and tested it, and it works.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @SandyGood Your code works perfect!  Thank you so much... Now if there was any way to set it up to get it to iterate through the named folder and all subfolders inside of it too, I would be forever in your debt. :) But, if not, it's okay.  I really do appreciate your help.  It works great!

Comment: I think you can just get the Folder ID of the subfolders and use the same code.  I don't think DriveApp cares if it's a folder or a subfolder as long as you have the Folder ID.  In other words you can access a subfolder directly.  Try it, and let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SandyGood I just meant having the code look through the folder and subfolders that are in it.  Kinda how some scripts are written to search and replace in a folder and its subfolders.  If it's not possible, its cool.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some code that gets a reference to a folder, and loops through the folder looking for spreadsheet files.

```
function getAllSheetsInFolder () {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Your Folder ID");
  Logger.log('folder: ' + folder);

  var sheetFiles = folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
  Logger.log("sheetFiles.hasNext(): " + sheetFiles.hasNext());

 while (sheetFiles.hasNext()) {
   var file = sheetFiles.next();

   var theFileType = file.getMimeType();
   Logger.log("theFileType: " + theFileType);


   var ssID = file.getId();
   Logger.log('ssID: ' + ssID);

   var thisSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);

   var sheet = thisSS.getSheets()[0];

   var cell = sheet.getRange(2,7);
   cell.setValue('Test Cell Set')
  };
};
```

This code uses a combination of `DriveApp` to get a list of spreadsheet files in a specific folder, then uses `SpreadsheetApp` to actually open the spreadsheet file, and write a value to a cell.

The `DocsList` Class is now deprecated.  My original code was using `DocsList` rather than `DriveApp`, but they are very different.  `DriveApp` can get a Folder, a list of files, and set and get other file information, but `DriveApp` can't open a spreadsheet file.  You have to open the spreadsheet file with `SpreadsheetApp`.  So the code must first get the folder, then a list of all spreadsheets in the folder, and the ID of each spreadsheet.  Then open the spreadsheet by ID.

Comment: I am a total beginner BTW, but I'm trying :).  I added some code to the bottom of your suggestion to try and set the value of (2,7) to T and not G, but no dice.  I am also getting a error message of TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null. (line 9, file "Code")

Comment: Thanks for updating your question.  You may want to remove the line:  `sheet.clearContents();`  I just noticed that.  I'm working on testing some code to see how it works.

Comment: continued....unless I delete line 9s code.  I'll keep on working at it.  Hmmm...Sorry I'm kind of new to this.  I am trying to set the value of (2,7) to RTI in the first sheet named "Class Data" to every spreadsheet in a folder.  and rename the 4th sheet in this spreadsheet to "RTI Data" Thanks so much for any help you can give.

Comment: That code assumed that the intent was to use an open spreadsheet, and write some data to the open spreadsheet.  You may not want that.  So if you don't need that, then just delete it.